# how to implement spring migration analyzer tool in existing application?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Hi am trying to implement spring migration analyzer tool in my application and I'm using jdk 1.5. But am getting Java.Lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad Version Number In .Class File exception.

when i run this file migration-analysis.bat am getting above error.

Please help me how to do this.

Comment: Please do add more info and code snippet to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you hava java 5 in your PATH and not an older version (run a `java -version` to check this).